# Ubuntu (22.04) keeps rebooting, even after reinstall

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I'm coming to this site because I'm a bit stuck with Ubuntu 22.04. Yesterday, after having a problem with the CUDA installation, I had decided to purge the nvidia drivers and reinstall everything. Everything seems to be working again, I can even run a game from Steam. This morning, I start the PC and the computer gets stuck on the boot screen, the one with the Ubuntu logo.

I read a couple of tutorials online and then go through recovery to try to fix the packages via dkpg. No success. I then try to go through the recovery root to purge the nvidia drivers again and reinstall them. The computer starts, arrives on the lock screen... then reboot, then return to the lock screen, then reboot and so on.

Not having much important files on this PC, I decide to reinstall Ubuntu (version 22.04). I reinstall the Ubuntu suite, taking care to format the entire disk and put the new version on a clean disk. I also decide not to ask for my password each time I open the system, so that I can go directly to my desktop.

The PC with the new version boots up, gets to the desktop (yes!) only for the mouse to freeze and the computer to reboot... and again gets stuck in a desktop loop for 5 seconds => reboot => desktop...

I tried to switch to nomodeset to reinstall the NVIDIA proprietary drivers but no luck.

I also managed to extract a couple of things from the recovering log, including :

- mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty) => this even though I did enter a name during the reinstallation...
- ACPI Bios Error: Attempt to CreateField of length zero.

I guess the problem is related to my GC, as the problems started to appear after the purge and reinstall of the Nvidia drivers.
So I'm not sure what else to do. I just hope the problem is related to Ubuntu, and not my graphics card...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are your temperatures high? Check that in UEFI (what some people still although incorrectly call BIOS ). If they rise without doing nothing it is time to clean your PC. A fresh install should not behave like this. Another thing you can try is boot from USB and choose ' try Ubuntu'. If that gets stuck as well I think it is a hardware problem. If that runs correctly it is something else ( assuming you did a check on the written medium and the .iso file ). With Ventoy you can write more .iso's to a usb device. So you can try another ( not Ubuntu of flavour ) distro ).

Comment: Temperatures are not high, but a weird behavior is that booting in recovery works, but not in classic boot. Perhaps because it's not using the GC but the integrated graphics?